# Emacs: fix height of certain windows

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to fix the height of a certain window like it is possible with **compilation** buffers using 
*compilation-window-height*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is [`window-size-fixed`](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/elisp-manual-21/elisp_441.html#IDX1477) buffer-local variable. If you set its value to `height` or `t`, that window gets fixed height.

E.g.

```
M-x set-variable window-size-fixed height
```