# How to configure emacs to open a wide compilation window?

Tags: emacs

Usually I edit source code in emacs with two (emacs-)windows side-by-side -- The second
windows opened via '*C-x 3*. Like this:

```
+------------+-------------+
|            |             |
| src1       |  src2       |
|            |             |
|            |             |
|            |             |
|            |             |
|            |             |
|            |             |
|            |             |
|            |             |
+------------+-------------+
| mini-buffer              |
+------------+-------------+
```

When I now start *compile*, eg with `F9`, the new `*compilation*` buffer replaces one of my *src*-buffers.

**Instead I would like the `*compilation*` buffer to open on-top of the mini-buffer**, if it is not visible already (if it is, use it, of course).

```
+------------+-------------+
|            |             |
| src1       |  src2       |
|            |             |
|            |             |
|            |             |
|            |             |
+------------+-------------+
|                          |
| *compilation*            |
|                          |
+------------+-------------+
| mini-buffer              |
+------------+-------------+
```

The `*compilation*`-buffer should have a height of about 30% of the while window or 6-10 lines.

How to accomplish that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772891/emacs-fix-height-of-certain-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use [popwin.el](https://github.com/m2ym/popwin-el).  I've never used it but it seems pretty customizable and the default config includes **compilation** already.